# Stable GCP PubSub API for Golang

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

We have an infrastructure where we use GCP Pubsub as a global pubsub and redis as a local pubsub.

Therefore we should create a component that would subscribe to GCP pubsub and publish incoming messages to redis.

To make that component as fast as possible we have decided to write it in Go because:

1. It compiles
2. It runs nativly on Linux (as opposed to .NET)
3. It's really fast while keeping simplicity (as opposed to C/C++)

Everything was fine and we were ready to GO (pun intended) but then I saw this:

[image]

It seems that there is no stable GCP Pubsub API for Golang.
Can I really rely on experimental version to run in production?

What should I do instead?
Maybe Golang is not necessary for this task?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell for sure but I personally do not read experimental as unstable. Experimental usually means that the library APIs might change going forward in non-backwards compatible way (i.e. you might need to rewrite your app if you want to upgrade) but it does not mean that the library is unstable. I suggest that you run your performance and stability tests and convince yourself that it is indeed stable.